# How can I filter the output of `ps fp` by the `COMMAND` column?

Tags: linux

I have

```bash
pgrep -U herman | xargs --no-run-if-empty ps fp
```

But I want to further filter by the `COMMAND` column by searching for `sh scriptName.sh Argument1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easier would probably be to just get `pgrep` to do that for you,

```
pgrep -U herman -f "sh scriptName.sh Argument1"
```

If things are more complicated than that, you can use the numbers `pgrep` delivers directly to check attributes of the processes as visible through /proc (it's the same place `ps` and `pgrep` check, so you're not even "awkward" doing that). For example

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env zsh
# /bin/bash should work too, but haven't checked.

for candidate in $(pgrep -U herman); do
  # skip any Python process
  grep -q bin/python3 /proc/${candidate}/cmdline || break
  # check whether this has any *.log file as stdin or stdout or stderr
  for fd in /proc/${candidate}/fd/{0,1,2}; do
    grep -q '.*\.log$' ${fd} && echo ${candidate} && break;
  done
done
```

would be a way to check the files that any of the processes (except python) has connected to their std*.